# regexIssueTracker not working in CruiseControl.net

Tags: regex, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to get an issueUrlBuilder to work in my CruiseControl.NET config, and cannot figure out why they aren't working.

The first one I tried is this:

```
<cb:define name="issueTracker">
  <issueUrlBuilder type="regexIssueTracker">
    <find>^.*Issue (\d*).|\n*$</find>
    <replace>https://issuetracker/ViewIssue.aspx?ID=$1</replace>
  </issueUrlBuilder>
</cb:define>
```

Then, I reference it in the sourceControl block:

```
  <sourcecontrol type="vaultplugin">
    ...
    <issueTracker/>
  </sourcecontrol>
```

My checkin comments look like this:

```
[Issue 1234] This is a test comment
```

I cannot find anywhere in the build reports/logs/etc. where that issue link is converted to a link.  Is my regex wrong?

I've also tried the default issueUrlBuilder:

```
<cb:define name="issueTracker">
  <issueUrlBuilder type="defaultIssueTracker">
    <url>https://issuetracker/ViewIssue.aspx?ID={0}</url>
  </issueUrlBuilder>
</cb:define>
```

Again, same comments and no links anywhere.

Anyone have any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to match a potentially multiline comment by using `.|\n` instead of just `.`, which doesn't match newlines by default.  Your first problem is that `|` has the lowest associativity of all regex constructs, so it's dividing your whole regex into the alternatives `^.*Issue (\d*).` or `\n*$`.  You would need to enclose the alternation in a group: `(?:.|\n)*`.

Another potential problem is that the lines might be separated by `\r\n` (carriage-return plus linefeed) instead of just `\n`.  If CCNET uses the .NET regex engine under the hood, that won't be a problem because the dot matches `\r`.  But that's not true of all flavors, and anyway, there's always a better way to match *anything including newlines* than `(?:.|\n)*`.  I suggest you try

```
<find>^.*Issue (\d*)(?s:.*)$</find>
```

or

```
<find>(?s)^.*Issue (\d*).*$</find>
```

`(?s)` and `(?s:...)` are [inline modifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) which allow the dot to match line separator characters.

---

**EDIT:** It looks like this is a [known bug](http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET-1589) in CCNET.  If the inline modifier doesn't work, try replacing `.` with `[\s\S]`, as you would in a JavaScript regex.  Example:

```
<find>^.*Issue (\d*)[\s\S]*$</find>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is good info, especially the inline modifiers.  Unfortunately, it still doesn't work for me.  Any other ideas?  How do   I know the url builder task is actually running?